# If element's text value exists in JSON, do this

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to see if an HTML element has a matching text in a JSON file, then change the link on the page according to the JSON. So for example, if the p tag contains New York City (Chelsea), change href to /lorem/ipsum1. I think I have the logic correct but I know I'm not executing it correctly.

Also note that within the p tag, there could be a space before and/or after the location name.

Thanks ahead for the insight!

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjPZaK

JSON

```
[
  {
    "Store": "New York City (Upper East Side)",
    "URL": "/lorem/ipsum1"
  },
  {
    "Store": "Lincoln Square",
    "URL": "/lorem/ipsum2"
  },
  {
    "Store": "New York",
    "URL": "/lorem/ipsum3"
  },
  {
    "Store": "New York City (Chelsea)",
    "URL": "/lorem/ipsum4"
  },
  {
    "Store": "Harlem",
    "URL": "/lorem/ipsum5"
  }
]
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <p> New York City (Chelsea) </p>
  <a href="/original/link">Link</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/7lu0y",
  async: false,
  success: function(data){

    if ($('.container p').text() == data.Store) {
      $('.container a').attr('href', data.URL);
    }

  }
});

});
```

Comment: Don't use `async: false`; it freezes the browser.

Comment: You want to loop over the array.

Comment: And after you loop over the array, you also need to `trim` the text because you have spaces before and after `New York City (Chelsea)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a little bit of newer javascript. You can change the content of your current `success` method to something like this.

```
const dataMap = new Map(data.map(item => [item.Store, item.URL]));
const text = $('.container p').text().trim();

if (dataMap.has(text)) { $('.container a').attr('href', dataMap.get(text)); }
```

Comment: Matus, thanks! This works! Just wondering, what is dataMap.get(text)? Asking since I'm not sure how that calls item.URL.

Comment: `dataMap` contains (key, value) pairs such as (`"New York City (Chelsea)"`, `"URL": "/lorem/ipsum4"`). When you call `dataMap.get(text)` with text filled with some value (key) -
 `dataMap.get("New York City (Chelsea)")` then the `.get` method fetches you the corresponding value, in this case `"/lorem/ipsum4"`